# Maintaning Historical data in Salesforce

Tags: analytics

I have requirement to display certain charts on a VF Page . On click of a button , I need to show a Comparison chart. Data of current quarter/month VS DATA OF PREVIOUS QUARTER/MOTN OF SAME YEAR /PREVIOUS YEAR .

What approach can  I follow to show it in the same VF page ?

1. Should I use a new object to store the historical data? (I.e storing relevant fields once it's inserted)
2. 
Using external analytics tool

3. Any other way?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Salesforce provide this functionality using Analytical Snapshots.

An analytic snapshot lets you report on historical data. Authorized users can save tabular or summary report results to fields on a custom object, then map those fields to corresponding fields on a target object. They can then schedule when to run the report to load the custom object's fields with the report's data. Analytic snapshots enable you to work with report data similarly to how you work with other records in Salesforce.

Please go through documentation here :

https://help.salesforce.com/HTViewHelpDoc?id=data_defining_analytic_snap.htm&language=en_US

https://help.salesforce.com/HTViewHelpDoc?id=data_about_analytic_snap.htm&language=en_US

http://help.salesforce.com/apex/HTViewHelpDoc?id=data_setting_up_analytic_snap.htm

https://help.salesforce.com/HTViewHelpDoc?id=data_mapping_analytic_snap.htm&language=en_US